# QGIS python file error for fetching script info

Tags: qgis, pyqgis

Currently i am working on automated map generation using Python coding in QGIS. i saved my all code but wile fetching the file into Script runner plug in i am getting error that you moved or deleted files. But i saved those all codes. whether it is issue of plug in or my code? I am just started to learning Python coding in QGIS theretofore anyone help is really valuable [image]

Comment: Does the file `D:/USER/SPA/Maps/Residual_maps_test.py` exist?